# JS Open Window And Alter User Agent

Tags: javascript, window, user-agent

I have a problem with a vendor ONLY working with IE. I am opening a window and passing credentials. If it is Chrome/FireFox/etc they block it. I am able to successfully change the user agent to imitate IE but not in combo with opening a window.

```
openWindow('https://www.IEOnlyVendor.com?credentials=abc123');
var __originalNavigator = navigator; // alter user agent string to IE 11
navigator = new Object();
navigator.__proto__ = __originalNavigator;
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () { return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;     WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MDDR; MS-RTC LM 8; rv:11.0) like Gecko'; });
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Perhaps create a window, change the user agent, then open the window.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to try something similar to how [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265600) changes the user agent of an *iframe*.

The important part (I added `contentWindow` param so you could (?) call on new window):  calling this function after injecting contents into empty window.

```
    var setUA = function(contentWindow) {
        if (Object.defineProperty) {
            Object.defineProperty(contentWindow.navigator, 'userAgent', {
                configurable: true,
                get: function () {
                    return 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5';
                }
            });
        } else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__) {
            contentWindow.navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
                return 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5';
            });
        } else {
            alert('browser not supported');
        }
    };
```

Comment: Awesome !.Sadly i am not able to achieve the same in IE8