# How to change the UserAgent of a window opened with window.open(), if possible?

Tags: javascript

It doesn't appear this is possible, looking at the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), but I came upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24715797/14573785) which doesn't make sense to me. The reason I want to do this is that I want to trick Bing into thinking it is being accessed by a mobile device/browser.

Comment: The code in that answer is purposed to be run in the window you're opening.

Comment: Why do you need to change the UserAgent?

Comment: @mx0 To trick a website into thinking a mobile device is accessing it.

Comment: @hackerman what's exactly your use case? who is going to access that website?

Comment: @mx0 I am making a website that opens to Bing on a smaller window. The site was ideally made for PC browsers, but I am not sure if it would work on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the *UserAgent* property using JavaScript.

From [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent)

> The Navigator.userAgent read-only property returns the user agent string for the current browser.

It is possible to change the `User-Agent` header for a [*XHR* request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) but it doesn't work for the *Chrome* browser.

Comment: You can, the code at the linked post works as it is. I'm not sure, if it changes the value of `userAgent` of the HTTP headers in the requests, though.

Comment: Browser will still send the true header, you cannot spoof  `User-Agent` anymore. I'm not sure about XHR request...

Comment: @Teemu The code at the linked post is meant for iframe.